# Do you recognize these foreign bottles?

Tags: spirits, liquor, identification

Among the spirits my grandfather left behind, these four bottles caught my attention. Are they interesting or rare?

[Liqueur Stregga](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0em4q8Q_8iEWDJZMk9pSV9qU0k)

[image: Liqueur Stregga]

[Tokay](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0em4q8Q_8iEdG05c3Q4Q1Z4d1E)

[image: Tokay]

[Anisette](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0em4q8Q_8iEVzR0clcyb0YtU2c/view)

[image: Brisette]

[Starka](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/GRhzZvjn2YjWK982XulEtKOep15EwpxWKwMhaqg3W45BjagzNGarS-hhFVwnSir5k3LRaa4l=w1440-h783)

[image: Starka]

Comment: Also: Brisette (?) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0em4q8Q_8iEVzR0clcyb0YtU2c

Starka
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0em4q8Q_8iEUl9vLUFaSnJYQlE

Comment: It's not **BR**isette, but **ANisette**. Marie Brizard is a french company, and you can find some of their [older products](http://www.prodimarques.com/sagas_marques/marie_brizard/marie_brizard.php) on this page. Unfortunately, can't find in english, NAA but just a comment, that someone can use if needed.

Comment: **Starka** has most probably been released by [Likwowin](http://likwowin.pl), a polish company. Again, nothing in English, sorry...

Comment: Can I determine if they're worth selling?

Comment: I have asked a friend who speaks polish to help me with the translation, I'll let you know if she has time for me and can have a look at it (no promises here as she's quite busy). I can't tell about the price right now, and I'm not a specialist so I'd rather not say any stupid and priceless advice :)

Comment: Strega is still sold in Italy

Comment: The correct spelling is [**Strega**](https://www.strega.it/liquore-strega/) as in the comment by @Alchimista

Answer (score 2):

Starka does not age in bottles, and has no vintage, so I don't think it can be of any interest.

Tokay ages very well, and 70 years old one might be interesting. On the other hand, I have a serious reservations regarding Richon leZion wine-masters of 1947. I would expect something along the lines of Carmel wines, but less refined. It definitely has a great historic value, because it was produced prior to Israel statehood. Ask your Jewish friends.

I have no say on other exhibits.

Answer (score 2):

I recognize Strega. It is a digestif from Benevento, Italy. Flavor can become unstable over time. Used in some modern cocktails as well. I don't have my books in front of me, but it is normally more yellow, from saffron. An herbal liqueur. There's recipes using it in the PDT book and sometimes in Imbibe magazine.